# Feed guess features into unsupervised learning classification?

Tags: classification, unsupervised-learning, feature-engineering, semi-supervised-learning

I've got an completely unlabeled dataset and my task is to classify it into positive and negative, two categories. As the data is unlabeled, I have to choose unsupervised classification; however, we also have some reasonable business guesses about possible important features influencing data's labels, such as age, gender ...

I would like to know how can I feed/force our guess features into the unsupervised learning and make it more precise?

Comment: Do you have a belief (say, probability) that given some range of ages, the example would end up in cluster #1 instead of #2?

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs yes I do have this belief. or at least a business suggestion or experience.

Comment: Another approach would be to do unsupervised learning and use the business guesses for sanity checks of the resulting classification.

Comment: @Deanna I would go with a model-based approach and take a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) as a base. The cluster assignments can be not only dictated by the relative distance to cluster centroids but also conditioned on the prior knowledge that you have. The generative model it is.

Comment: @Bernhard I guess that would take too much time, to check every possible unsupervised learning method......

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs apart from my prior knowledge I would like that the unsupervised model could also give me more informtion, not only give classifications on prior knowledge. Can GMM do it?

Comment: What "more information" are you looking for? To me, it looks like you want to build an unsupervised clustering model that is informed/guided by some prior information. Do you have an idea how the data could've been generated? Like, if you are asked to provide the process to create synthetic examples, would you be able to write such a program? There is no need to be 100% precise, just the main traits.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs I see. I'm OK with coding but unclear about details (or I should not be entangled in details? For example I've found some unsupervised clustering algorithms done with prior knowledge, but the prior knowledge inputs they need are centroids or pre-determined clusters, while I prefer rules.